# What can make something immune to Crusader's "Iron guard's Glare" stance

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

My DM put us in front of an undead skeleton and a purple worm. My Crusader attempted to use *Iron Guard's Glare*, but the DM ruled that the enemies were not affected by it.

What are the rules for immunity against *Iron Guard's Glare*? Is it Intelligence? Willpower?

Comment: May I suggest you to ask your GM for a balance ? If your GM prefers it not to work on some foes, maybe it could be more efficient on the few ones against who it still works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RAW (Rules As Written), there is no option to resist it. The *Iron Guard's Glare* stance simply causes opponents **that you threaten** to take a penalty on attacks against **all targets that are not you**.

The "fluff" (descriptive text) of the ability implies that it is simply an intimidating glare you make, however this is not relevant to the game mechanics. It might also represent trained interference with the enemy's attacks.

If your DM has made a *house-rule* that says it is a type of intimidation, then non-intelligent creatures would not be affected by it. A non-intelligent creature is simply not capable of recognizing or responding to threats in that manner.

Comment: It’s worth noting, perhaps, that this was likely a quite-intentional choice on the part of the authors. *Iron guard’s glare* is a decent, but not amazing choice, but making it highly situational by tying it to intimidation and thus Fear effects makes it simply not worth using. It might make “sense” that a purple worm would ignore it, but ultimately it makes the game worse because an otherwise-reasonable option becomes a non-option, or worse, a trap. The choice not to include rules language defining *iron guard’s glare* as Fear seems to me a reaction to the over-use of Fear immunity.

Comment: @KRyan Why not make that an answer?

Comment: It could also have little to no effect if it is visual intimidation if you're going against blind/tremorsense creatures, as a houserule.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by tzxAzrael, there is nothing apart from DM fiat that can prevent *Iron Guard's Glare* penalty.

Note, however, that the penalty applies:

- only to foes that you threaten
- only for attacks against your allies

and that the foe knows ahead of hand that any attack against another than you will take this penalty (allowing an intelligent enemy to make a trade-off).

If this was not your situation (ie, you were threatening a foe who attacked your ally and the DM rule that the penalty didn't apply) then the DM is house-ruling it.

In this case, you might want to discuss this with your DM and:

- either ask him if it was a mistake: he may not have been familiar with it and thought it was a fear-based effect
- or if he has a house-rule ask him to remove it: it's hard enough to tank in D&D without the DM sabotaging it further
- or ask him the exact details about this house-rule, and the option to take another first-level stance if you feel that it's no longer worth it (it's already border-line without the house-rule...)

*Note: -4 AR is -20% chances of hitting; however if you have 4+ AC more than your ally, it's still easier to hit them than you... and unfortunately this does not scale, and squishy targets should rarely be close enough to you for you to threaten those that may attack them (unless they use range attacks). Oh, and it doesn't scale. It's limited enough in effect, no need to house-rule it really :x*

Comment: Saying “-20% chances of hitting” is misleading, or inaccurate, depending on how pedantic you want to be. Ignoring nat-1s and nat-20s, it reduces your chances of hitting by 20 *percentage points*, which is different from making your chance of hitting 20% less than it was.

Comment: @KRyan: Indeed, it's a gross simplification. It also ignores your current chances of hitting (if you have 95% of hitting or can only hit on 20, ...). Nonetheless, I find it a useful approximation during play :)

Comment: It was a mutual decision for this fight. But we want to know for later use. Thanks for the - 20% rule of thumb!

Comment: Each + or - 1 to hit is *about* +/-5% to hit, but like KRyan and Matthieu M have said, it is an extreme simplification of the actual probabilities, and ignores a lot of potential factors. Still, it's handy for "quick and dirty" approximations. Basic math: "1 in 20" is equal to "5 in 100" or 5%.